# Creating a cellular network identifier and user then saving it in a txt file

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program to identify a mobile number and what that cellular network is then save the rest of the number on a text file.

I already have a function that accepts 3 digits and identify what that cellular network is. The problem is that the rest of the of the numbers when input the function doesn't accept it.

Also I tried using both int& and string& at the same time which I think is not possible.

My idea is that the enterdata's "data" will change depending on the question and since the mobile number is an integer i used the int& and string& for the names

```
string numbercheck() //check network
{
if (number == 918 || number == 920 || number == 928) //Smart or TnT
{
    return " Is a Smart or Talk and Text number";
}
}
void enterdata(string data, int& data2, string& data3) // Inputing datas
{
cout << "Please Enter your " << data.c_str();
cin >> data2;
}
void input1() // Saving/Creating New
{
system("cls");
PrintMessage("New Data");
enterdata("Mobile Number +63", number, "");
cout << number << numbercheck() << endl;
enterdata("First name", "", firstname);
}
```

Comment: Here's a tip for handling phone-numbers: Don't use integer types. That will cause leading zeroes to disappear.

Comment: function `numbercheck` is missing return statement in case of `if` condition being false and leads to undefined behavior

Comment: I tried using string& for data2 and erased data3 but the if statements above in the numbercheck says no operator == matches these operands